# different Limit number of post on different archive page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, paging

I set post per page from setting>maximum post per page to 20
I have 2 different custom post type 'book' and 'author' for archive of each of them I want to load different number of post in page. I want to load 20 book per page in book archive and 5 post in author archive in each page , I also use
WP-PageNavi plugin
here is my code

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'Author','paged' => $paged,'posts_per_page' =>5 ); 
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="writer-link col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

    <div class="writer-row1 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 image-right">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail',array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 pull-right writer-content">
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <h4><?php the_field('auth-trans'); ?></h4>  
    <?php if ( get_field('writer-bio') ) { 
        echo '<p>'.get_field('writer-bio').'</p>';} ?>

            <span>...</span>
    </div>
</div>
</a>

   <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>           

    <div class="wp-pagenavi row">
        <div id="wp_page_numbers text-center col-sm-6 center-margin">
            <ul>
                <li class="active_page text-center"><?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $loop )); } ?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
```

no problem with book archive it load 20 post. but I don't know how can make author page to load just 5 post per page and after it load 5 first post it is going to next page.

any idea would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for this problem is using WP hooks, in this case you need pre_get_posts. You can find reference on this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

Scroll down to "Changing the number of posts per page, by post type" and there you can set your custom post type to load different number of posts.

Hope this helps